Spark Connect questions
I am currently using Spark Connect inside a Docker container to send Python tasks through Airflow.
I frequently encounter unreleased memory, which forces me to reboot the Spark Connect every night.
My memory even explodes when i write to parquet. Here's how I write to parquet:
spark_df.write \
    .mode(saveMode='overwrite') \
    .option("header", 'true') \
    .parquet(f"{filepath}", compression="snappy") \

spark_df.unpersist(True)

I tried all PySpark techniques to release memory:

spark.stop() at the end of the session
df.unpersist() at the end

Nothing changed. For exemple, à loaded à 1.5M rows dataframe, took 1.5Gb in memory before parquet writing. While writing, the memory usages peaks to 5/6Gb and stays there.
I have 2 questions:
First, do I have to use Spark Connect without any external master/worker? Here's my docker-compose file:
version: '3.8'

name: spark_connect_cluster
services:

  spark-connect-main:
    container_name: 'spark-connect-main'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: spark.Dockerfile
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 16g
    ports:
      - "50131:4040"
      - "50132:15002"
    command: bash -c "bash /etc/init.d/ssh start &&
      /opt/spark/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1 --master local[*] &&
      tail -f /dev/null"
    tty: true
    networks:
      - default
      - astro_spark
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080
      - HADOOP_HOME=/etc/hadoop
      - HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
      - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    volumes:
      - spark-shared-volume:/tmp

volumes:
  spark-shared-volume:

networks:
  astro_spark:
    external: true

Secondly, are there any other solutions to free memory usage?
Thank you

I have a similar problem. It seems like every time data are fetched from a iceberg table via spark connect the memory usage of spark connect increases. Eventually, I need to restart the docker container to make it work again. If someone has an idea how to fix that, I would be glad to read from you.
